# Change the default color code of URL

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Friends
I want to change the default blue color of the folloowing URL to RED , I tried using 
style="color:red but it didnt help.
Please suggest a better approach.

```
<div class="row-fluid">
    <div class="span12" style="color:red"><a href="/event/alert/recipient/list/${alertStatusForm.forAlert.id}" class="underline">${fn:length(alertStatusForm.totalNotSentRecipient)}</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: you should give !important for your style

Comment: @VIVEK-MDU why use harsh overrides when a little better specificity will do just as well?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to edit the actual **a** element. You can do this multiple ways.

**In your CSS File**  (this will edit all links)

```
a:active, a:link, a:visited {
    color: red;
}
```

**With Inline Styling**

Apply the style directly to the **a** element.

```
<a style="color: red" ...
```

**Or, create a class in your CSS File**

You could create a class in your CSS file:

```
a.myLink:active, a.myLink:link, a.myLink:visited {
    color: red;
}
```

Then apply the class to your link:

```
<a class="myLink" ...
```

Answer (score 2):

You applied to color to div, you need to change `color` of `a` instead of `div`

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/8cZJx/)**

```
<div class="row-fluid"><div class="span12" ><a style="color:red" href="/event/alert/recipient/list/${alertStatusForm.forAlert.id}" class="underline">${fn:length(alertStatusForm.totalNotSentRecipient)}</a></div></div>
```

Its generally a good practice to use **css class instead of directly changing style** using style attribute.

*CSS*

```
.red-color-a
{
   color:red;
}
```

*HTML*

```
<div class="row-fluid"><div class="span12" ><a class="red-color-a" href="/event/alert/recipient/list/${alertStatusForm.forAlert.id}" class="underline">${fn:length(alertStatusForm.totalNotSentRecipient)}</a></div></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

I see that your `<a>` link has the class "underline".
You can add this css code to your CSS file to make the text red:

```
.underline a:active, .underline a:link, .underline a:visited {
    color: red;
}
```

or apply it directly in the HTML like so:

```
<div class="row-fluid">
    <div class="span12"><a style="color:red" href="/event/alert/recipient/list/${alertStatusForm.forAlert.id}" class="underline">${fn:length(alertStatusForm.totalNotSentRecipient)}</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to target the `<a>` tag instead of its parent span :

```
<a style="color:red"> ... </a>
```

The default styles from the anchor tag are going to overwrite the `<span>` tag that is wrapping it.

Answer (score 1):

use text decoration none

```
<a href="http://www.google.com" style="text-decoration:none;color:red">Visit google</a>
```